# How to disable Share button in Office web app in SharePoint Online

Tags: office-web-apps

I have a document library in SharePoint Online. I need to disable or hide 'Share' button in the office web apps when a user opens a document. I need this happen for the users with read permission level. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I've got a similar question for SP2016 On Prem: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/204696/office-online-server-hide-buttons

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am not aware about your Office configuration nor your infrastructure,in the case you can control your reverse proxy you can drop response header but I thing it might be worthy try this [workaround](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/05b66707-e67d-4b42-b363-096efd1b90f6/disable-share-button-in-office-2016?forum=Office2016ITPro) before, apply